# default location of MediaWiki extensions directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mediawiki

I recently install MediaWiki on Ubuntu 10.04 using all the default settings. I'm looking to install an extension. Where is the *extensions directory* located by default? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions